# Need UTHSCSA ImageTool source code

Tags: computer-vision

I wonder if anybody has a copy of source code of UTHSCSA ImageTool

The links in the homepage (http://ddsdx.uthscsa.edu/dig/) are all broken

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://ddsdx.uthscsa.edu/dig/pub/IT/IT3SDK.zip) worked fine for me.